# 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_NET'

Tags: python, sockets

While entering the following in terminal(Python 2.7):

```
import socket
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_NET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
   sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_NET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_NET'
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

It is `AF_INET`.
Try,

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```